# Computing the Laplace transform of an expression

Tags: probability-distributions, integration, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

I would like to find the Laplace transform of the following expression with respect to the Laplace parameter s

$ \int_{z=u}^{\infty} e^{-az/c} g^{'}(\dfrac{z-u}{c}) \int_{x=0}^{\infty} \varphi(z-x)dF(x) dz$

where $g(x) = \dfrac{d}{dx} [1- E_{\beta}(-\eta x^{\beta})]$ and $E_{\beta}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^{k}}{\Gamma(\beta k +1)}$ is the Mittag-Leffler function, and $g^{'}(x)$ is the derivative of $g(x)$ and $F(x)$ is the distribution function of a random variable X.

Changing the order of integration does not help.

Comment: Requesting suggestions from the math community regarding the question posted.